# Could not resolve placeholder for context:property-placeholder

Tags: java, database, spring, properties, environment-variables

I am trying to set my app to use different data source definitions, based on an environment variable, but I'm running into the below error. I looked at many similar questions, but they don't seem to be the same.

I have set up multiple properties files:

```
env-dev.properties
env-test.properties
env-prod.properties
env-.properties
```

I have created a system property called MEM_ENV with the value "dev"

My spring xml file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath*:*env-${MEM_ENV}.properties" />
    <bean id="mongoDataSource" class="com.iLearn.persistence.base.MongoDataSourceImpl">
        <property name="server" value="${mongo.server}" />
        <property name="port" value="${mongo.port}" />
        <property name="dbName" value="${mongo.dbName}" />
        <property name="userName" value="${mongo.userName}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mongo.password}" />
    </bean>
```

My properties files look like this:

```
mongo.server=aServer.com
mongo.port=10003
monog.dbName=aDBName
mongo.userName=aUserName
mongo.password=aPassword
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
    message org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'mongoDataSource' defined in class path resource [springAppConfig.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.server' in string value "${mongo.server}"

description The server encountered an internal error (org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'mongoDataSource' defined in class path resource [springAppConfig.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.server' in string value "${mongo.server}") that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'mongoDataSource' defined in class path resource [springAppConfig.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.server' in string value "${mongo.server}"
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    com.iLearn.security.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:43)
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using Spring version 3.2.1.Release

Comment: Try location="classpath:/env-${MEM_ENV}.properties" />

Comment: it doesn't work - it creates a different exception - FileNotFound

Comment: Ok it means that the file in previous case was resolved, so You need only to be sure about the right value of the MEM_ENV system variable and that mongo.server property is defined in env-dev.properties file, I can't see other cases here.

Comment: Same thing I was thinking, but I just can't seem to see the problem, so I thought I'd see if there was something more subtle I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the system variable didn't work until I rebooted my machine. After that it worked fine, (once I fixed my typo of monog.dbName).

I'm not sure if it was the reboot of Windows, or the restart of Eclipse, or restart of Tomcat that fixed the problem, as all of those occurred with my reboot.

Hope this helps someone else - if you have this problem, first try a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `classpath` resolver wrongly. Remove one unnecessay `*`.

Change from,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*env-${MEM_ENV}.properties" />
```

to

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:env-${MEM_ENV}.properties" />
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference. With one or both * I still get the above exception. If I remove the "classpath*: " all together, I get a different exception, that it cannot find the properties file. This leads me to think that in this case it is finding the properties file...